# YA Novel with a boy trapped inside an RPG computer game

Tags: story-identification

Storyline is that 2 kids playing an RPG end up trapped in the game. One of the characters is a female orc that he named after a teacher he didn't like. Don't remember the other main character. The beginning of the story sets up with dialogue between them through the ingame chat.

I believe it is a recent book (published post 2000) and would show up as sci-fi/fantasy and young adult.

Answer (score -2):

In case you're still looking for the title, it's called "Out of the Dark World" and it's by Grace Chetwin, 
[https://www.amazon.com/Out-Dark-World-Grace-Chetwin/dp/1930094086](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1930094086) There's the link if you want a copy

Comment: Could you add any details to confirm that this is the story being asked about?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your answer to describe the matching elements.

Comment: Downvoting as link-only answer. Please add details to fully explain your answer.